# "found.000" directory after fsck

Tags: mount, disk, fsck

I'm having troubles accessing some files on an external disk giving me the following error:

```
ls: cannot access file.pdf: Input/output error
```

Some solutions suggested performing a disk check with `fsck` which I did.

Now when I mounted my disk again. I have found a new folder on its root `found.000`.

*What is that folder? Is it safe to delete?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `found.000` folder seems to be the output folder used by `fsck` in order to write the files it recover from the bad area on the disk.

It is possible that some corrupted data on your disk can be found there.

I'd suggest keeping this folder for a while.

I think that you can delete this folder when you'll be sure that no important data should be recover.

You can read more about it here :

- [What are found.000 folders and why are they created ?](http://techsalsa.com/what-are-found000-folders-and-why-are-they-created/)
- [How to recover windows found.000 files](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-recover-chk-files-created-by-chkdsk-and-scandisk/)

> Note that Unix system usually save such files in `/lost+found` ([see
>   this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18154/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-lostfound-folder-in-linux-and-unix))

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have accepted your answer because it actually answers my question. But I may ask one more. Is there a way to recover those "files" on Ubuntu ?

Comment: @eliasah - Thanks for accepting my answer.  I don't know how to recover those "files" in Ubuntu.  I've update my answer with a link about `lost+found`. Is it possible that this external drive has any connection to windows (NTFS , was connected to windows OS, etc)? usually `found.000` reference to windows (hence the links in my answer).

Comment: Well this drive isn't in NTFS format and I do use it on Windows sometimes. It's a 1T disk and I had around 1.9GB in found.000. So I didn't want to be throwing eventually valuable data.

Comment: @eliasah - I want to help without causing any harm... if most of the HDD wasn't used before the `fsck` it is possible that the 1.9GB in the `found.000` is just bad sectors of unused area of the HDD. I see two options for next steps: 1) check if any important file is missing 2) try to find a recovery utility

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I believe that this is what I will do !